# changing fragment's place when user select a tab android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an application where I use two fragments(the first for displaying a list, the other for text) and an actionBar.

I want, when a user selects a certain item from the actionBar, to exchange the two fragments (the one displaying the list displays the text, and the other displays the list).

thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an action to your Xml declaration like this;

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_changeFragment"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:onClick="doChange"
    android:title="Display List"/>
```

And then inside your java code, create a function with the name "doChange"

```
public void doThis(MenuItem item) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   NewFragment fragment = new Newfragment();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.whateverYouHave, fragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```